# Can you cast between pointers that point to different template class instances?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Let's say I have a container class template called `Pool` and an abstract class called `PoolObject`

The class template `Pool` allows a user to create a Pool that contains a specific type of pool objects. For example:

```
template<class T, size_t pool_size>
Pool()
{
    // assert that type T is derived from PoolObject

    public:
        int grab(){};
        void release(int object_id){};

    private:
        std::array<T, pool_size> pool_members_;
}
```

Now let's say I want to create a few different pools to manage a few different object types.

```
class PoolObject1 : public PoolObject{};
class PoolObject2 : public PoolObject{};
class PoolObject3 : public PoolObject{};
class PoolObject4 : public PoolObject{};

Pool<PoolObject1, 100> pool_1;
Pool<PoolObject2, 100> pool_2;
Pool<PoolObject3, 100> pool_3;
Pool<PoolObject4, 100> pool_4;
```

Let's now say I want to create a factory function for grabbing pool objects, and a destroy function for releasing pool objects. A simple implementation would feature a switch statement to determine what pool should be used.

```
int factory(int object_type)
{
    switch(object_type)
    {
        case 1:
        return pool_1.grab();

        case 2:
        return pool_2.grab();

        case 3:
        return pool_3.grab();

        case 4:
        return pool_4.grab();

    }
}
```

While simple, I would have to implement this same case statement for any method that operates on these pools. For example, the destroy method.

```
void destroy(int object_type, int object_id)
{
    switch(object_type)
    {
        case 1:
        return pool_1.release(object_id);

        case 2:
        return pool_2.release(object_id);

        case 3:
        return pool_3.release(object_id);

        case 4:
        return pool_4.release(object_id);
    }
}
```

As more object types are defined, the switch statement grows, which then becomes a pain to manage and update every method.

A simpler solution would be to have a look up table to grab the pool in question and then call the appropriate method.

For example, I could attempt to store pointers to each pool in an array.

```
std::array<void*, 4> pool_ptrs =
{
    &pool_1,
    &pool_2,
    &pool_3,
    &pool_4
};
```

By having this array of pool pointers, I can now rewrite my factory and destroy methods as follows:

```
int factory(int object_type)
{
    return static_cast<Pool*>(pool_ptrs[object_id])->grab();
}

void destroy(int object_type, int object_id)
{
    return static_cast<Pool*>(pool_ptrs[object_id])->destroy(object_id);
}
```

However, this code WILL NOT compile. The compiler complains that my `Pool*` is missing template parameters.

So I understand why my code won't compile, however, I don't know what the appropriate solution is. I essentially want to use the class template as an "abstract class". I don't want to cast a pointer to `Pool<Object1, 100>` or a pointer to `Pool<Object2, 100>`, I just want to cast a pointer to `Pool`

So my question: can you cast between pointers that point to different template class instances?

Comment: Instead of `switch` statements and integer type ids, templates and types. Instead of overloads, template specializations or just instantiations. Also, be sure that that there really is a performance problem to be solved (in some way, e.g. pools): **measure**.

Comment: Out of curiosity, assuming this isn't an academic exercise, why not use the existing proven `Boost.Pool` library? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't think I understand your comment. Could you expand more? I assume I'm using templates incorrectly.

Comment: @Dai I wasn't aware boost had a pool library. Boost libraries always seem like overkill whenever I do start reading into though.

Comment: Why are you trying advanced stuff like a  memory pool if you don't understand the langage enough? It would make sense to get some practice with more usual things first and also read good books to properly learn the language. If your approach is so complicated, then you might hurt performance instead of improving it. It does not make much sense to have a factory that hide type information and then have to switch on type so in my opinion the whole approach is wrong.

Comment: As much as possible avoid posting pseudocode.  Post actual code, simplified.  `template<class T, size_t pool_size> Pool()` is not actual code; I assume the rest isn't either.  Second, if you want polymorphism, you have to enable some kind of type erasure.  This can be inheritance based or ducktyped; C++ does not force a relationship between `Pool` template type instances.  You can add one if you want; just write an abstract interface that isn't dependent on the template parameters and inherit from it.

Comment: @Phil1970 I've been working with C++ on and off for the past couple years. I don't have much experience with template programming and am starting to get more into it. At some point you just have to put the book down and start trying things out to truly learn them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is pretty trivial:

Yes, you can cast pointers, it the different instances share a common base class. Just like with ordinary types. You'll need to add a `PoolBase`. Note that this isn't a template, it's the common non-template interface.

And no, you can't have a `PoolBase::get(int object_type)` which returns a `PoolObject1`, `PoolObject2`, or `PoolObject3` depending on the runtime condition `object_type`. Return types are determined at compile time.